# GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle start server in background

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, websocket

I know the command to start the server normally using

```
php app/console gos:websocket:start
```

But, How can we start the server in background?

And Is there any way to `stop/restart` the server, I'm unable to find it on SO or GitHub?

Comment: What do You mean in background? `php app/console gos:websocket:start &` runs command in background. Are You trying to use it in production? PHP internal server is for development only

Comment: Yes I want to start the web socket server in production. I know we can run process in background using & but that doesn't give possibility to stop/restart the server.

Comment: because php server was never meant to be ran in production environment. You should install apache/nginx or other web server with php handler

Comment: I've apache installed on the server. So I've to open a specific port to listen the requests, right?

Comment: I suggest you read the apache or nginx documentation

Comment: https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/ShipInProduction.md  We can run the server in production like this, my question is how I can stop/restart the server ?

Comment: If your using *nix box you could use Supervisord in a setup similar to http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSJobQueueBundle/master/installation#setting-up-supervisord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to start at background we use `app/console gos:websocket:server --env=prod & disown`
you can also use nohup to run websocket server in background
to stop it, we search websocket server proccess and kill it
`ps aux | grep gos:websocket`, `kill -9 -pid-`

Comment: Thanks for the way, I've used the same approach in different way.

Answer (score 1):

i managed to put my git hook bash-script to work like this:

```
echo -e "stopping websockets";
pid="$(pgrep -f gos:websocket)"
if [ -n "${pid}" ]; then
    kill -9 ${pid};
    echo -e "killed websocket ${pid}";
fi

echo -e "starting websockets"
/dir/app/console gos:websocket:server -e=prod -n > /logdir/ws/ws.log 2>&1 &
```

this way it kills and starts ws server and puts it into the background without user interaction and the output is not lost.

if anybody wonders about the syntax, its a double fork and closing outputs 
http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Background-processes-in-post-receive-hook-td6235357.html